# I am facing a compilation issue while doing npm start in my angular component

Tags: angular, angular-components

I am trying to render the component dynamically for one  of my screen. I am using componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory and viewContainerRef.createComponent api to achieve the same . I have defined the variable  " `loadedComp : GlobalDynamicComponenet;`" and loading the component dynamically like 
 `this.loadedComp = <GlobalDynamicComponenet>this.registry.getComponent("<component name>");`

Then I am trying to retrieve the factory object by using below code ,

```
const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.loadedComp);
```

the above piece of code throws error says  --

***TS2345: Argument of type 'GlobalDynamicComponenet' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Type<{}>'.
[0]   Property 'apply' is missing in type 'GlobalDynamicComponenet'***

The beauty is if I comment the above piece , start the server  then uncomment the same piece of code and then everything goes fine. Angular finds the factory component even though it has compilation issue and I could render the component successfully. Its just that npm start is failing. Can anyone of you help me to get rid of compilation issue?

Global dynamic component class:

```
***import { Component,Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector:'abstract-comp',
  template: ` <h1></h1>
  `
})
export class GlobalDynamicComponenet
{
  @Input() parentOrder={};
}***
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

That's not a component error, that's a type​ error. You're not typing your objects consistently. First you define them as type A and then try to assign it type B {}. That's why it won't compile.

The Typescript is there to help you. And forces you to make consise decisions. Try specifically typing every variable and object in this piece of code and I'm sure you see what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

//Below code is to get all the available factories . This will retrieve all the components defined in the entry components in the ngModule.

var factories = Array.from(this.componentFactoryResolver['_factories'].keys());

//Below code will get the factory class using the component name which you are passing.

var factoryClass:any = >factories.find((x: any) => x.name === this.columns["ComponentName"]);
 const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(factoryClass);

//Below code will create the component using the factory.

const ref = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(factory);

//Below coed will set the value of the input param which you are trying to load dynamically.

(ref.instance).parentOrder=this.order;